# How to set @property for each element in a list using python?

Tags: python, class

I'm creating a class to store time.Say

```
class TimePoint(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # a time list to store year, month, day, hour, minute, second
        self.time_unit = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

And I want to limit the range of each element in `self.time_unit`, for example, `0 < self.time_unit[1] <= 12`, which means `month` range 1~12.So, I want to use `@property` to decorator `self.time_unit`'s each element.Say

```
import arrow


class TimePoint(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.time_unit = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
        self.oor = False
        time_now = arrow.now()
        self.year = time_now.year
        self.month = time_now.month
        self.day = time_now.day
        self.hour = time_now.hour
        self.minute = time_now.minute
        self.second = time_now.second

    @property
    def t_unit(self):
        return self.time_unit

    @t_unit.setter
    def t_unit(self, value):
        if value < 0 or value > 9999:
            self.time_unit[0] = self.year
            self.oor = True
        if self.time_unit[0] < 0 or self.time_unit[0] > 9999:
            self.time_unit[0] = self.year
            self.oor = True

        if self.time_unit[1] < 0 or self.time_unit[1] > 12:
            self.time_unit[1] = self.month
            self.oor = True

        if self.time_unit[2] < 0 or self.time_unit[2] > 31:
            self.time_unit[2] = self.day
            self.oor = True

        if self.time_unit[3] < 0 or self.time_unit[3] > 24:
            self.time_unit[3] = self.hour
            self.oor = True

        if self.time_unit[4] < 0 or self.time_unit[4] > 60:
            self.time_unit[4] = self.minute
            self.oor = True

        if self.time_unit[5] < 0 or self.time_unit[5] > 60:
            self.time_unit[5] = self.second
            self.oor = True
```

But, `@property` and `@t_unit.setter` just decorator the whole list `self.time_unit` , not elements in `self.time_unit`.So, how to decorator `self.time_unit`'s element? Should I write `@property` for each element?

```
@property
def t_unit_first(self):
    return self.time_unit[0]
```

Comment: You really should use the `datetime` lib to work with dates. You will never implement all edge cases properly.

Comment: @Klaus.D they imported `arrow` which is a "human friendly date time library", sort of like `requests` vs `urllib`

Comment: `property` is not supposed to be used on instances, rather, it is mean to be used on methods in a class. It doesn't make sense to use it on elements in a list, unless those elements are callables I suppose...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I understand this.I just want to limit the range of elements in a list. My statement is not clear.

Comment: Then don't use property.

Comment: @Klaus Is there a  better way to store a time point? Which can limit range automatically.

Comment: A [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) will handle validation and raise an expection when you try to enter an invalid date. Of cause you can add any other constraint manually and it should even be more easy. Arrow offers similar functionality, but just importing it is not enough.